# Wrong Canonical url link

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, rel-canonical

I have a weird problem.

I have a page that changed URL (because it's parent changed name).

Example
Link
https:www.mysite.com/my-services/service-1

is now:
https:www.mysite.com/services/service-1

the canonical url however is still the original one:
https:www.mysite.com/my-services/service-1

which is wrong. (it should be the new link)

This is what I tried:

- I had the redirection plugin to handle the redirect, but have switched that one iff > does not solve the problem
- I have switched of Yoast > doesn't help
- I switched on Yoast again - and explicitely changed the canonical link in the Yoast SEO section of th page > that solves it.

However I don't want to manually have to change a canonical like this. Is there a better solution? Am I missing something? Can I regenerate canonical tags in batch?
So many questions - is there someone with an answer?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Ingrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset your indexables. There are a couple of ways to do this - you can use a [WP-CLI command](https://developer.yoast.com/customization/yoast-seo/indexables-cli/) (`wp yoast index`), or you can use the [Yoast Test Helper plugin](https://developer.yoast.com/blog/yoast-test-helper-easy-testing/).

If you install the Yoast Test Helper Plugin, you can go to Tools > Yoast Test. In the "Yoast SEO" box with a bunch of buttons, use the "Reset Indexables tables & migrations" button to flush them. You can then uninstall the plugin, remove your manually-entered canonical URL, and the default (autogenerated) canonical URL will be fixed.

Theoretically, anytime you make a change such as changing a parent page URL, that should trigger Yoast to automatically update its indexables. So it may be worth opening a GitHub issue so they're aware this didn't happen as intended.

Comment: Hi  @WebElaine - thanks so much for your answer, that seems to have solved it! I must say that the Yoast plugin has been pretty reliable, but lately it is getting more buggy. Quite annoying. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: WP CLI command didn't seem to work for me, but the Yoast Test Helper plugin did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the status of the page from "published" to "draft" and then back to "published" and the canonical url was updated.